# How to use the dotnet-pack --version-suffix with csproj?

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core

I'm trying to use the .net Core tools RC4 dotnet pack command to create a nuget package with a suffix.

I can create "MyProject.1.2.3.nupkg" successfully but I want "MyProject.1.2.3-beta.nupkg".

According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/dotnet-pack) the --version-suffix "Updates the star in -* package version suffix with a specified string."

I've managed to find where dotnet pack is getting it's version from - dotnet pack uses msbuild under the [covers which uses the `<version/>` element](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Adding-nuget-pack-as-a-msbuild-target) in the csproj file. For example `<version>1.2.3</version>` creates a file called "MyProject.1.2.3.nupkg".

If I set the `<version/>` in the csproj to something like 1.2.3 and specify --version-suffix beta then it doesn't append the -beta but it does build.

If I set version to be `<version>1.2.3-*</version>` then dotnet restore breaks saying '1.2.3-*' is not a valid version string.

I think I'm close; what have I got wrong?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#common-top-level-properties), the `Version` property override the version on packing, instead, use the `VersionPrefix`.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VersionPrefix>1.0.0</VersionPrefix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And use the command to pack solution:

```
dotnet pack --version-suffix beta
```

Optionally you can set `VersionPrefix` and `VersionSuffix` in `.csproj` file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VersionPrefix>1.0.0</VersionPrefix>
  <VersionSuffix>alpha</VersionSuffix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: One significant drawback I've seen to using VersionPrefix in the CSPROJ is it forces you to edit the version through direct manipulation of the CSPROJ text file. The IDE (package properties) can no longer be used as it shows the VersionPrefix value but will write the <Version> tag if this field is modified. Not knowing the original requirements this appears to me like a bug.

Answer (score 10):

The `--version-suffix` argument simply sets the `$(VersionSuffix)` msbuild parameter. From the `dotnet pack` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack):

> With the project's version suffix configured as $(VersionSuffix) in the .csproj file, pack the current project and update the resulting package version with the given suffix:
>
> ```
> dotnet pack --version-suffix "ci-1234"
> ```

Now, *I think* that the `--version-suffix` only works with the `<VersionPrefix>` value in the csproj and also fails to provide a mechanism for setting the version prefix.

You can override *any* msbuild parameter via `dotnet` calls by using the `/p:Parameter=Value` syntax. If you're invoking this from a shell terminal, such as git bash, you'll need to enter this as `//p:Parameter=Value`.

Now, I've actually found it to be much easier to just avoid the entire prefix/suffix shenanigans as it has always seemed fragile to me. I instead just simply use the `<Version>` property defined in my csproj as follows:

```xml
<Version>$(Version)</Version>
```

> EDIT: I'm not sure if this behavior has changed or if `dotnet` always supported this, but it appears that the above csproj change is not required to properly set the version during `dotnet pack` operations. This actually makes tons of sense, since the xml tags in a csproj file are simply setting msbuild properties and the `/p:Property=Value` syntax also sets those properties.

And then for your automated builds, you can resolve your prefix/suffixes as you wish and then combine them with a `-` to produce the full version string. Another requirement not documented is that the version suffix *must* begin with a character to be semver compliant. A common suffix is something like `ci-<unix-timestamp>`.

```sh
prefix=<prefix-value>
suffix=<suffix-value>
dotnet pack //p:Version="$prefix-$suffix" path/to/csproj
```

Comment: As an update -- the version tag is NOT required in your csproj files. I don't put it in any of my csproj files and instead of the `-p:Version=$version` when running through git bash

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but according the [dotnet pack documentation examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack#examples),  you can use this MSBuild property:

```
dotnet pack -p:PackageVersion=2.1.0
```

And I've confirmed that you can use it with pre-release versions as well (e.g., `2.1.0-preview`).

This allows people to set the `<Version>` element in the .csproj file (and use the IDE they want) and then override it during the build process. At my company, we have a Powershell script that invokes `dotnet pack` and sets the version number based on which branch the code was built from. If it's from the dev branch, then we add `-alpha`, but if it's from the master branch, then we don't add anything.